# Beginner with jQuery... validating form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am learning jQuery right now and am looking to validate form fields with it.

The registration form in question is at http://taehee.pumpl.com/register.php

The basic code for the form field I made is:

```
<div id="register">
        <form action="">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <ol>
            <li><label for="username">유저네임</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" size="32" type="text" ></li>
            <li><label for="email">이메일</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" size="32" type="text"></li>
            <li><label for="password">비밀번호</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" size="32" type="password"></li>
            <li><label for="password2">비밀번호 확인</label>
            <input id="password2" name="password2" size="32" type="password"></li></li>
        </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div> <!-- register -->
```

I've loaded jQuery in the header using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I also created a script with the following code:

```
$('#register').validate({
rules: {
    username: {
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    password: {
        minlength: 4,
        required: true
    },
    password2: {
        equalTo: "#password"
    }
},
success: function(label) {
    label.text('OK!').addClass('valid');
}
```

});

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I fill out the form and it doesn't matter whether the fields are all wrong.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You're using referring to a jQuery plugin that you didn't link to. The `validate()` function isn't part of the jQuery core file.

Comment: Its the jQuery validation plugin, isn't it (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) For plugins to work you need to link to them using `<script>` tags, or include it with your source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small/easy-to-fix issues here. First as the comments state you need to include the validation plugin, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

This pulls it from the Microsoft CDN, or grab and host from your site.  The second issue is that [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) works on `<form>` elements, so you need this instead:

```
 $("#register form")
```

Or, give the ID to the `<form>` directly and use that selector.

[Here's an updated version with both fixes in place](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tDH9r/), also jQuery has released [1.4.1](http://jquery14.com/day-12/jquery-141-released) and [1.4.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/), you may want to consider upgrading to get those bug fixes, just change the `1.4.0` in your `src` URL to `1.4.2`.

Comment: Thank you. I made both of the changes and everything works as intended now. :)

Comment: @Victor - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept an answer if it resolves your problem via the check-mark on the left :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that feature. I checked your answer and will make sure to do that from now on. :)